# LWUIT Painter : How to make an image the background?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am trying to use Painter to make a certain jpg become my background.

```
    mapScreen = new Form("Map");
        try 
        {
            Image image = Image.createImage("/res/try.jpg");
            map = new Map(image);
            mapScreen.addComponent(map);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.print("Error\n\n"+e.getMessage());
            mapScreen.addComponent(new Label(e.getMessage()));
        }
```

And for the map class,

```
public Map(Image image)
{
    this.mapImage = image;
    painter = new Painter()
    {
        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clippingRect) 
        {
            g.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawImage(mapImage, getX(), getY());
        }
    };
}
public void initComponent() 
{
        setX(0);
        setY(0);

        getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        getSelectedStyle().setBgPainter(painter);
        getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        getUnselectedStyle().setBgPainter(painter);
}
```

The problem with this is that the image doesn't show up at all and when I try to debug, It doesn't even enter the paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clippingRect)...
The code

```
try 
        {
            Image image = Image.createImage("/res/try.jpg");
            map = new Map(image);
            mapScreen.addComponent(map);
        }
```

is successful.

Can anyone tell me how to do it properly?
And also, if anyone know how to do panning on an image larger than the size of the screen, Can you help me with that also? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setBgTransparency to 255 and don't call the clipRect method.

You can look at the bg painter code within Component.java which is pretty flexible.